# Why are browsers making PUT requests for static assets on my site?

Tags: http

Our site hosts static assets at `/assets/…`. In debugging a font-related issue, I looked through our logs for unusual activity. I found a bunch of requests like these

```
method path                         referer
PUT     /assets/js/40-8b8c.chunk.js https://mysite.com
PUT     /assets/fonts/antique.woff2 https://mysite.com/assets/css/mobile-ef45.chunk.css
```

The requests come from thousands of different IP addresses all over the world. Some common IPs: `1.0.147.0`, `2001:8a0:6a06:2d00:25c5:9a67:dda7:5a83`, `73.61.14.163`, `80.189.209.30`.

I don't see any pattern in the `User-Agent`s. The only HTTP methods are `HEAD` (odd, but fine), `GET` (expected), and `PUT` (very suspicious).

The paths are all resources that exist on the origin server. I expect `GET` (and maybe `OPTIONS` and `HEAD`) requests to these URLs in the normal course of loading popular pages. It's the `PUT`s that have me confused.

There are lots of other requests from the same IP/`User-Agent` combinations right around these requests. Some of those look very normal: `GET /`, `GET /api/session`, etc. There are also some others that look suspicious like `PUT /api/some-read-only-data`.

I haven't been able to identify any code in our system that would cause a browser to make `PUT` requests to these paths.

I have no evidence that this activity is malicious. It could certainly be a broken browser plugin.

Has anyone seen this sort of behavior?

Comment: What other requests do you see around the PUT requests, from the same IP? That is, if you split out the activity of a particular client, what are they doing when the PUT occurs? (Or, for that matter, is there any surrounding activity, or are the PUTs just isolated requests?)

Comment: Good question, @GordonDavisson. I'll update to clarify

Comment: I now believe this was an internal coding error. The PUTs getting logged were sub-requests from the edge, not requests from browsers. I suggest this question be closed.